# How to set the values for JSONPath Syntax dynamically?

Tags: java, json, groovy, jsonpath

This is the JSON:-

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName" : "doe",
  "age"      : 26,
  "address"  : {
    "streetAddress": "naist street",
    "city"         : "Nara",
    "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "date"  : "2018-10-09",
      "number": "0123-4567-8888"
    },
    {
      "type"  : "2018-10-12",
      "number": "0123-4567-8910"
    }
  ]
}
```

And below is the JSONPath syntax to fetch the "number":-

```
$.phoneNumbers[?(@.date=="2018-10-09")].number
```

I want to change the date value to future dates. For example my above syntax should look like this after changing the date:-

Increased date for next 2 months.

`$.phoneNumbers[?(@.date=="2018-12-09")].number`

Can we do it using groovy? I ant to automate it, Since, I have lot many JSONPath syntax. So, it'll be really tedious task to change each and every date manually.

Comment: could you add more context for your question. share the code...

Comment: I have not written any code. I am thinking of implementing this. What happens is when the above date will be passed, then the JSONPath syntax will not work. So, i am planning to automate this. That,once the above date will pass, i will run the code so that the new date will be updated. By the way, I have updated the question.

Comment: what about usual groovy code like: `json.phoneNumbers.find{it.date==d}.number`

Comment: What if, I have only the JSONPath only? what'd you suggest then?